# Lookbehind in JavaScript. Space after words

Tags: javascript, regex

How I can find space after *at* or *me*? 
It's don't work in javascript:

```
\s(?<=at|me)
```

Comment: Do you mean a space that is immediately after "at" or "me"?

Comment: sorry, yep, i mean whitespace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of [more or less magic tricks](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/mimic-lookbehind-javascript) which you can use to simulate lookbehind, for example:

```
s = "space after at or me !"
// "space after at or me !"
String.prototype.reverse = function () { return this.split('').reverse().join('') }
s.reverse().replace(/ (?=ta|em)/g, "@").reverse()
// "space after at@or me@!"
```

That said, in simple cases like yours you can just capture the preceding group and paste it in a replacement:

```
s.replace(/(at|me) /g, "$1@")
// "space after at@or me@!"
```

Answer (score 1):

> How I can find space after at or me

This regex should do the job:

```
\b(?:at|me)(\s)
```

#### [Online Demo](http://regex101.com/r/yP0mZ6)

Comment: hi @anubhava, thanks for answer, but i need whitespace after at or me

Comment: @parkov, see my answer. It matches the whitespace

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript does not natively support look-behind (ES6 regular expressions will, though).

You could work with the properties of the global `RegExp` object to work around that:

```
var input = "How can I match the space after at or me in JavaScript?";
var regex = /\b(at|me)(\s)/ig;
var match, before, after;

while (regex.exec(input)) {
    before = RegExp.leftContext + RegExp.$1;
    match  = RegExp.$2;
    after  = RegExp.rightContext;

    console.log(before);
    console.log(match);
    console.log(after);
}
```

will log

```
"How can I match the space after at"
" "
"or me in JavaScript?"
"How can I match the space after at or me"
" "
"in JavaScript?"
```